# Is this a metonymy?

Tags: metonymy

> I suppose if a book features a face it usually indicates it's lower
> quality.

https://deliabattie.wordpress.com/tag/book-covers/

Can you say "book" instead of "book cover"? Is this acceptable in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not really say this is metonymy, because metonymy is about using an attribute or metaphorical image, like using "the Crown" to mean "the monarch" or "the royal family", or saying "the press" to mean "the publishing industry".  In this case, the cover is literally part of the book, so saying "the book cover features X" is simply more precise than saying "the book features X".

There is always some degree of ambiguity in usage like this; if this sentence appeared without any context, it would be ambiguous, because the face could be *in* the book instead of simply on the cover.  But the context of the article makes it clear that we are talking about book covers, so there is not much ambiguity here and the sentence is perfectly clear and acceptable.